# Nova pergunta com utilizador apagado

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, usuarios

Esta pergunta [Datatable usando o datatable eu descobri issp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46738/datatable-usando-o-datatable-eu-descobri-issp) foi criada por um utilizador mesmo agora que entretanto foi apagado (acho). O que fazer numa situação destas?

- Fechar a pergunta;
- Sinalizar a pergunta;
- Tratar como outra pergunta qualquer;
- Outra opção (Qual?);

[Edição] Pelo que vi agora o utilizador anda a testar o site.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Como se põe a linha a volta da imagem?

Comment: Colocando a imagem dentro de um bloco de citação com `>`

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto. Mas também já vi de outra forma, fica acinzentado.

Comment: Talvez em outro site? Em alguns sites (SO por exemplo), o bloco de citação é cinza

Comment: Não, aqui mesmo @bfavaretto. Não deve ser de citação, deve ser outra coisa.

Comment: Já sei é <kbd></kbd>, vê na edição.

Comment: Ah é. Isso é coisa do @brasofilo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o único problema fosse o autor ter excluído a conta, você poderia tratá-la como qualquer outra pergunta. Caso a pergunta tenha outros problemas graves, como esta tinha, vote para fechar, excluir, e/ou sinalize (conforme o caso os seus privilégios).

Comment: Só para esclarecer, e no caso de ser uma pergunta razoável, mas faltar alguma informação? Fecha-se como "Não está claro o que está perguntando"? Uma vez que o utilizador se apagou.

Comment: Sim, feche como não é claro se achar que a salvação depende do autor. Nessa pergunta, o autor usou duas contas distintas, ambas posteriormente apagadas, uma para perguntar e outra para responder (repare que uma tem id 20720 e a outra 20721).

Comment: Ok, vi mal os id's sorry ;)